# Dropdown menu in R plotly?

Tags: r, plotly

I saw [on this blog](http://moderndata.plot.ly/new-feature-dropdown-menus-in-plotly-and-r/)  that using plotly in R it would soon be possible to insert dropdown menu, which is great ! However, it seems to be a new feature included in the 4.0 release of plotly, about which I haven't found any information.

Do you know if it's possible to get a developpment version ? Do you have any information on a date of release for plotly 4.0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cran has just been updated to plotly 4.5.2 and now everything is fine for me !

Answer (score 1):

You can create dropdown menus with Plotly R Library  2.0. Here to see for an [example](https://plot.ly/r/dropdowns/).

Comment: Maybe this hasn't anything to do with my plotly version (3.6), but when I execute the code you linked (with require(dplyr) require(plotly) before), I don't get the map, I can see only the bar on the right, the title and that's it. No dropdown, and no map.

Comment: oups I posted to quickly : when I save as web page and open it in chrome, I get the map, but still no dropdown menus. And in Rstudio (0.99.903), no map